# in a single thread application server(flask) that handling a time consuming request(CPU-bound), what will happen to other requests?

Tags: python, flask, wireshark

**in short**:
I expect that while a single-threaded server is handling a request other requests must be dropped, (so the browser must continuously send that HTTP request to finally get the response) but in my example, this is not happening. why?

---

in my simple flask app I have two routes that, corresponding view function returns as follow:

1. `/fibo` that returns a JSON that contains the start and end of execution of view function that calculates Fibonacci 37. I use the recursive version of Fibonacci as a CPU-bound process.
   `start_process` and `end_process` value is in the form of `%M:%S` (the current time's minute and second will be displayed).
2. `/fibo2` that contains the same logic as `/fibo`. (i will use it to better illuster my question)

```
an example of returned JSON response is like this:
{"start_process":"02:02",
"fibo execution time":"7.22","fibo(37)":24157817,
"end_process":"02:09"}
```

I run the app by `flask run` command. I send two `get` requests to `/fibo` route, in separate tabs with the browser (while the first tab is loading I sent the second request)
the responses for each one are:

```
{"start_process":"02:02",
"fibo execution time":"7.22",
"fibo(37)":24157817,
"end_process":"02:09"}
```

and

```
{"start_process":"02:09",
"fibo execution time":"6.93",
"fibo(37)":24157817,
"end_process":"02:16"}
```

as the JSON responses illuster the second process started after that the first request is finished its job.

the Wireshark log of this process is :
[image]
in this section, my question is why after that for each of the separate requests TCP handshake happened the second request's `get` was sent after receiving the response of the first request? **I expect that I must see lost HTTP packets, in Wireshark**

---

I repeat this step and send requests to each of routes `/fibo` and `/fibo2` the results are:

```
{"start_process":"29:41",
"fibo execution time":"16.30",
"fibo(37)":24157817,
"end_process":"29:58"
}
```

and

```
{"start_process":"29:43",
"fibo execution time":"16.21",
"fibo(37)":24157817,
"end_process":"29:59"
}
```

this time the requests are started approximately at the same time. ( maybe the 2-second delay is because of the time spent entering the second request in the browser.) but this time the time of executing the Fibonacci is doubled.

this time as the Wireshark shows the HTTP requests are sent separately from each other.
[image]

---

codes for flask app:

```
import re
from flask import Flask, request
from fibo import fib_t
from datetime import datetime

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/home')
def hello():
    return 'hello '

@app.route('/fibo')
def cal_fibo():
    start_p = datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S")
    v, duretion = fib_t(37)
    end_p = datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S")

    d = {'start_process':start_p,'fibo(37)':v,'fibo execution time':duretion, 'end_process':end_p}
    return d

@app.route('/fibo2')
def cal_fibo2():
    start_p = datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S")
    v, duretion = fib_t(37)
    end_p = datetime.now().strftime("%M:%S")

    d = {'start_process':start_p,'fibo(37)':v,'fibo execution time':duretion, 'end_process':end_p}
    return d


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

fibo module:

```
def fib(a):
    if a == 1 or a==2:
        return 1
    else:
        return fib(a-1) + fib(a-2)


def fib_t(a):
    t = time.time()
    v = fib(a)
    return v, f'{time.time()-t:.2f}'


if __name__ == '__main__':
    print(fib_t(38))
```